# Listeners to aggregations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, listener, aggregation

I am new to elasticsearch. I am storing the values for response times of some services over the period of time. What I want is the way to get notified when the average value for the response time goes below some threshold value. Is there any way that elasticsearch can notify me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way Elasticsearch can send notifications. The best you can do is to have your client send an [Avg Aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) command to Elasticsearch, read the response and send notification through some custom logic.